# RegEx for splitting a string while ignoring brackets' content

Tags: java, regex

I have an expression that I want to split by operator, which is located between two pairs of brackets without interacting with operators in them. For example:

```
"(z/(2+t))/((2.0+var)*(x/y))"
```

Should become:

```
["(z/(2+t))", "/", "((2.0+var)*(x/y))"]
```

I have tried to use the following RegEx:

```
((?<=[+*/\\-])|(?=[+*/\\-]))(?![^(]*[)])
```

But the splitting occurs between inner expressions:

```
["(z", "/", "(2+t))", "/", "((2.0+var)", "*", "(x/y))"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a much cleaner answer than this but this should do the job:

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      // starting here with the result of your regex operation
      String[] yourOutputArray = {"(z", "/", "(2+t))", "/", "((2.0+var)", "*", "(x/y))"};

      List<String> listy = new ArrayList<String>();
      String s = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < yourOutputArray.length; i++){
          s += yourOutputArray[i];

          if(characterCount(s,"(") > 0 && characterCount(s,"(") == characterCount(s,")")){
              listy.add(s);
              s = "";
          }else if(s.length() > 0 && characterCount(s,"(") == 0){
              // this must be an operator we want to split on
              listy.add(s);
              s = "";
          }
      }

      // listy is the result you are looking for
      System.out.println(listy); // [(z/(2+t)), /, ((2.0+var)*(x/y))]
    }

    public static int characterCount(String input, String character){
        return input.length() - input.replace(character, "").length();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/2ZeJLN/1/) might help you to separate them:

```
.+\)(\/)\(.+
```

It creates a single group in the middle which includes the first <kbd>/</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: actually, i would wanna see it more flexible, not only for this particular case but rather as if there can be any expression with any set of operators

Comment: 2*((a-b)+(b*(a+10))); (2+a)-(2*a)+(b*(c*c)) returning `["2", "*", "((a-b)+(b*(a+10)))"]`; `["(2+a)", "-", "(2*a)", "+", "(b*(c*c))"]` respectively, but actually there can be any number of such complex expressions containing simpler ones